# How to open a website protected by Cloudflare using Chromedp?

Tags: google-chrome, go, chromedp

How to open a website protected by Cloudflare? such as https://coinlist.co,

I just want to open https://coinlist.co using Chromepd with headless = true flag, but Chrome prompts that "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software", and the chrome page blocks at the Cloudflare page. It seems like Cloudflare can detect the Chromedp.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the [github.com/go-rod/stealth](https://github.com/go-rod/stealth) package based on the [puppeteer stealth plugin](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) like below:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
    "github.com/go-rod/stealth"
)

chromedp.Run(
    ctx,
    chromedp.Evaluate(stealth.JS, nil),
)
```

If that doesn't work then you may need to use a captcha solver like 2captcha.

Comment: Ho to use it ? Could you give me complete example code please? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate. What's the HTML status code you're receiving?